# how to create multiple select box in amp web which 1 combobox according to another combobox value

Tags: amp-html

```html
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>

<form method="GET"
  class="p2"
  action="/"
  target="_top">
    <div class="ampstart-input form-elem">
      <label for="sel1" class="form-label">Select1</label>
        <select name="sel1"
          id="sel1"
          on="change:AMP.setState({jsonData: {key : event.value}})">
          <option value="a">car</option>
          <option value="b">shoes</option>
          <option value="c">book</option>
          <option value="d">food</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="ampstart-input form-elem">
        <label for="sel2" class="form-label">Select2</label>
        <select name="sel2"
          id="sel2">
          <option [text]="jsonData[(jsonData.key)]">a example</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    <amp-state id="jsonData">
      <script type="application/json">
        {"key" : "",
         "a":["mercedes","bmw"],
         "b":["sandal","red shoes"],
         "c":["novel","comic"],
         "d":["rice","mie"]
       }
      </script>
    </amp-state>  
  </form>
```

how to make the combobox 2 contain multiple value which get from json...now the selectbox only contain 1 option selectbox which join the array..I want to get option as many from array of json value...
for example: 
if combobox 1 select book so the combobox 2 will contain novel and comic.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Results]

Is what the screenshot shows above your expected outcome? If so, you're just missing the amp-form script it looks like (if the amp-bind script is the only one you're running).

```
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
```

Also check out the [Linked Dropdowns](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/linked_dropdowns/) page on [AMP By Example](https://ampbyexample.com). It may be helpful for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: no, I want select 2 have 2 option : 
-novel 
-comic  
not only 1 option novel, comic.

Comment: Check the Linked Dropdowns page I linked in my answer. You're going to need to use amp-mustache and amp-list as stated on that page so it actually loops through your JSON array values rather than printing them as one string.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Craig, you need to use `amp-list` and `amp-mustache` to generate content.

`amp-list` can take its results using a `[src]` binding and will iterate over each result using the provided `template`.

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to get `amp-list` to render the `option` tags only.
A valid workaround would be to generate the `select` tag as in the linked dropdown example.
In order to do so, you should wrap your items in an object so that `amp-list` doesn't have an array but an object, and render the template only once, but you can iterate over your results witch `mustache`.

You can do it like this :

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>

<amp-state id="jsonData">
<script type="application/json">
  {
    "key": "a",
    "a": {"items": [{"name": "mercedes"},{"name": "bmw"}]},
    "b": {"items": [{"name": "sandal"},{"name": "red shoes"}]},
    "c": {"items": [{"name": "novel"},{"name": "comic"}]},
    "d": {"items": [{"name": "rice"},{"name": "mie"}]}
  }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<form method="GET" class="p2" action="/" target="_top">
  <div class="ampstart-input form-elem">
    <label for="sel1" class="form-label">Select1</label>
    <select name="sel1" id="sel1" on="change:AMP.setState({jsonData: {key : event.value}})">
      <option value="a">car</option>
      <option value="b">shoes</option>
      <option value="c">book</option>
      <option value="d">food</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="ampstart-input form-elem">
    <amp-list [src]="jsonData[jsonData.key]" items="." layout="fixed-height" width="auto" height="25">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <label for="sel2" class="form-label">Select2</label>
        <select name="sel2" id="sel2">
          {{#items}}
            <option>{{name}}</option>
          {{/items}}
        </select>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
  </div>
</form>
```